# Pandas: How to count distinct values in a group by dataframe?

Tags: pandas, count

I was searching stackoverflow since yesterday for similar problem, but I was unable to find one that match my scenario.

I've started with a multiple column dataframe that I am trying to get the count/sum of distinct values of featureB grouped by featureA.

```
df_gby= df.groupby (['featureA', 'featureB')]
df_gby['featureA', 'featureB'].head () # I am interested only on these 2 columns
featureA featureB
------------------
str1     feature1
str1     feature2
str1     feature3
str2     feature3
str2     feature4
str3     feature1
str3     feature2
str3     feature2
str3     feature2
str3     feature5
```

I want to get something like this as result:

```
featureA featureB_count
-----------------------
str1     3
str2     2
str3     3
```

Please note that str3 has feature2 duplicated 3 times. It should count as 1, so the total of distinct values should be 3, not 5. I am not sure if this happens in df_gby, but, for sure it happens on the initial df. May be there is no duplicates on df_gby as it is a result of group by of the 2 features, but I am highlighting this just to get some tips about it.
Theses 2 columns are strings/objects, not numbers.
If the groupby operation above return distinct values on featureB it is a simple matter of counting how many groups are in featureA isn't ? (even so, I was unable to get this number. groupby dataframes are trick, not every regular function is available on groupby dataframes...)

I suspect this is the case, as size on df_gby return 1 for each pair, as far I can see.

```
featureA featureB
----------------------------
str1     feature1     1
str1     feature2     1
str1     feature3     1
str2     feature3     1
str2     feature4     1
...(truncated output)
```

The dataframe is large, more than 5000 lines, so I can't inspect it properly to be sure there is no repeating entries on featureB after groupby operation as the output is truncated, but as I said, for sure there is repeating featuresB on the original df for a particular featureA.

I appreciate your help,

Comment: You can use `nunique` check `df_gby.groupby('featureA')['featureB'].nunique()`

Comment: @Shubham Sharma: "df_gby.groupby('featureA')['featureB'].nunique()" returns AttributeError: 'df_gby' object has no attribute 'groupby'.
Also, df.groupby ('featureA')['featureB'].nuique () returns AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nuique'

Comment: I guess you are making a typo mistake use **`nunique`.**

Comment: Yes, I did a typo on the second attempt. However it worked on the original df, not on df_gby. I mean "df.groupby ('featureA')['FeatureB'].nunique()". Thank you man !